# Automatic download of Power Bi reports

Tags: powerbi

I have made a power bi report for staff performance. I filtered each staff by their name to see the performance under various parameters. My difficulty is I only want to download reports of low performing staff. I have given a score from 1 to 10 to each staff. Staff having score less than 5 are low performing. So every month I want to download the report only for low performing staff. Is there any way to automatically download reports.

As of now, I am manually entering the staff name and then download the report of each staff.

Answer (score 0):

The [e-mail subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-subscribe) is the feature that is the closest match to what you want. However, this selectivity what to be sent and what not, isn't possible without some kind of automation from your side (e.g. using Power BI REST API to change the parameter values, refresh the report and export it).